# there any field in view that display Display author and date information

Tags: views

I have created a view for my project, is there any field in view that displays "Display author and date information" ?

Comment: are you displaying node information in views?

Comment: I had crated view of articles page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you mean the date posted and making assumptions also on entity types.

**For nodes:**
Author: Add the "Content: Author" relationship and then the "User: Name" field.
Date: Add the "Content: Post date" field.

**For comments:**
Author: Add the "Comment: Author" field.
Date: Add the "Comment: Post date" field.

Answer (score 0):

I have created similar views which display node author and node post date.

Code Snippets:

```
$view = new view();
$view->name = 'news';
$view->description = '';
$view->tag = 'default';
$view->base_table = 'node';
$view->human_name = 'News';
$view->core = 7;
$view->api_version = '3.0';
$view->disabled = FALSE; /* Edit this to true to make a default view disabled initially */

/* Display: Master */
$handler = $view->new_display('default', 'Master', 'default');
$handler->display->display_options['title'] = 'News';
$handler->display->display_options['use_more_always'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['access']['type'] = 'perm';
$handler->display->display_options['cache']['type'] = 'none';
$handler->display->display_options['query']['type'] = 'views_query';
$handler->display->display_options['exposed_form']['type'] = 'basic';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['type'] = 'full';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['options']['items_per_page'] = '10';
$handler->display->display_options['style_plugin'] = 'default';
$handler->display->display_options['row_plugin'] = 'fields';
/* Relationship: Content: Author */
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['uid']['id'] = 'uid';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['uid']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['uid']['field'] = 'uid';
/* Field: Content: Title */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['id'] = 'title';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['field'] = 'title';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['label'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['alter']['word_boundary'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['alter']['ellipsis'] = FALSE;
/* Field: Content: Body */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['body']['id'] = 'body';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['body']['table'] = 'field_data_body';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['body']['field'] = 'body';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['body']['label'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['body']['element_label_colon'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['body']['type'] = 'text_summary_or_trimmed';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['body']['settings'] = array(
  'trim_length' => '600',
);
/* Field: Content: Post date */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['created']['id'] = 'created';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['created']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['created']['field'] = 'created';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['created']['label'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['created']['element_label_colon'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['created']['date_format'] = 'custom';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['created']['custom_date_format'] = 'd m Y';
/* Field: User: Name */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['id'] = 'name';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['table'] = 'users';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['field'] = 'name';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['relationship'] = 'uid';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['label'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['element_label_colon'] = FALSE;
/* Sort criterion: Content: Post date */
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['created']['id'] = 'created';
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['created']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['created']['field'] = 'created';
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['created']['order'] = 'DESC';
/* Filter criterion: Content: Published */
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['id'] = 'status';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['field'] = 'status';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['value'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['group'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['expose']['operator'] = FALSE;
/* Filter criterion: Content: Type */
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['id'] = 'type';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['field'] = 'type';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['value'] = array(
  'article' => 'article',
);

/* Display: Page */
$handler = $view->new_display('page', 'Page', 'page');
$handler->display->display_options['path'] = 'news';
```